# Not allowed to connect to Database using sqlcl

Tags: liquibase, sqlcl

I have installed Liquibase Version: 4.21.1 and SQLcl Version: 23.1.0.089.0929 in my Windows 10 PC.
Even though I have set the class paths for both, I always need to change my path to

```
cd D:\Software\sqlcl\bin
```

to login to Oracle database like

```
sql username/Password@localhost:1521/xepdb1
```

Is there a way to connect to DB any where within the PC?

Can anybody help me to solve this issue.